# Saving last set visibility of widgets

Tags: java, android

I've created a sign up/log in system in my app. I created those pages (sign up and log in) into a same activity class. The components i have -
Four edit texts one for name, second one for phone number, then email then password and a two buttons sign up and log in below.
To make those into a same activity I just change their visibility. So i set the log in button visibility GONE and sign up button VISIBLE in the on creat method and the user click on the sign up button after filling everything i set visibility GONE for sign up button,name andphone also VISIBLE for log in button. And then the user need to back for check the email and click on the link has been sent to the email. Afther verification user need to come back again into the app and need to click on the log in button. But as i seted visibility for the widgets into the on create method in a way that it will make a sign up page the user need to fill everything again and acess the log in button. What I need is to save the last visibilities of the widgets that I can restore them again when the user come back and open the app after verification. Please help me.
Here is my MainActivity.java file -

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initialize(_savedInstanceState);
        com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        initializeLogic();
    }
    
    private void initialize(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
        
        parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
        lin1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin1);
        dilouge = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dilouge);

//here is the initialisation part I just cut it for make the question short 
        sign_in = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sign_in);
        fauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        
        sign_up_box.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View _view) {
                
            }
        });
        
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View _view) {
                if (fillemail.getText().toString().equals("") || fillpass.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "please enter the above requirements!");
                }
                else {
                    fauth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(fillemail.getText().toString(), fillpass.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, _fauth_sign_in_listener);
                }
            }
        });
        
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View _view) {
                if (fillname.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "please enter your name!");
                }
                else {
                    if (fillphone.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "please enter your phone number!");
                    }
                    else {
                        if (fillemail.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                            SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "please enter your email!");
                        }
                        else {
                            if (fillpass.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "please enter your password!");
                            }
                            else {
                                fauth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(fillemail.getText().toString(), fillpass.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, _fauth_create_user_listener);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        
        sign_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View _view) {
                
            }
        });
        
        sign_in.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View _view) {
                name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mob.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                dilouge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                sign_up.setText("Sign In");
                button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        
        _fbd_child_listener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot _param1, String _param2) {
                GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>> _ind = new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};
                final String _childKey = _param1.getKey();
                final HashMap<String, Object> _childValue = _param1.getValue(_ind);
                
            }
            
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot _param1, String _param2) {
                GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>> _ind = new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};
                final String _childKey = _param1.getKey();
                final HashMap<String, Object> _childValue = _param1.getValue(_ind);
                
            }
            
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot _param1, String _param2) {
                
            }
            
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot _param1) {
                GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>> _ind = new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};
                final String _childKey = _param1.getKey();
                final HashMap<String, Object> _childValue = _param1.getValue(_ind);
                
            }
            
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError _param1) {
                final int _errorCode = _param1.getCode();
                final String _errorMessage = _param1.getMessage();
                
            }
        };
        fbd.addChildEventListener(_fbd_child_listener);
        
        fauth_updateEmailListener = new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<Void> _param1) {
                final boolean _success = _param1.isSuccessful();
                final String _errorMessage = _param1.getException() != null ? _param1.getException().getMessage() : "";
                
            }
        };
        
        fauth_updatePasswordListener = new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<Void> _param1) {
                final boolean _success = _param1.isSuccessful();
                final String _errorMessage = _param1.getException() != null ? _param1.getException().getMessage() : "";
                
            }
        };
        
        fauth_emailVerificationSentListener = new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<Void> _param1) {
                final boolean _success = _param1.isSuccessful();
                final String _errorMessage = _param1.getException() != null ? _param1.getException().getMessage() : "";
                
            }
        };
        
        fauth_deleteUserListener = new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<Void> _param1) {
                final boolean _success = _param1.isSuccessful();
                final String _errorMessage = _param1.getException() != null ? _param1.getException().getMessage() : "";
                
            }
        };
        
        fauth_phoneAuthListener = new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task){
                final boolean _success = task.isSuccessful();
                final String _errorMessage = task.getException() != null ? task.getException().getMessage() : "";
                
            }
        };
        
        fauth_updateProfileListener = new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<Void> _param1) {
                final boolean _success = _param1.isSuccessful();
                final String _errorMessage = _param1.getException() != null ? _param1.getException().getMessage() : "";
                
            }
        };
        
        fauth_googleSignInListener = new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task){
                final boolean _success = task.isSuccessful();
                final String _errorMessage = task.getException() != null ? task.getException().getMessage() : "";
                
            }
        };
        
        _fauth_create_user_listener = new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> _param1) {
                final boolean _success = _param1.isSuccessful();
                final String _errorMessage = _param1.getException() != null ? _param1.getException().getMessage() : "";
                if (_success) {
                    name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mob.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    dilouge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    sign_up.setText("Sing In");
                    btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    map.put("name", fillname.getText().toString());
                    map.put("phone", fillphone.getText().toString());
                    map.put("email", fillemail.getText().toString());
                    map.put("password", fillpass.getText().toString());
                    fbd.child(fillname.getText().toString()).updateChildren(map);
                    //code for verification link send on user email
                    
                    fauth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification() .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                showMessage("Verification Link has been sent to your email !"); } else {
                                showMessage ("Verification Link could not be sent !");}
                        } });
                    //powered by ashishtechnozone
                    
                }
                else {
                    SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), _errorMessage);
                }
            }
        };
        
        _fauth_sign_in_listener = new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> _param1) {
                final boolean _success = _param1.isSuccessful();
                final String _errorMessage = _param1.getException() != null ? _param1.getException().getMessage() : "";
                if (_success) {
                    //code for verification status checking
                    
                    verified = fauth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified();
                    //powered by ashishtechnozone
                    
                    
                    if (verified) {
                        SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "successfully logged in!");
                        intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else {
                        dialog.setTitle("please verify your email!");
                        dialog.setMessage("verification link has been sent to your email ");
                        dialog.setCancelable(false);
                        dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface _dialog, int _which) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                        dialog.create().show();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), _errorMessage);
                }
            }
        };
        
        _fauth_reset_password_listener = new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<Void> _param1) {
                final boolean _success = _param1.isSuccessful();
                
            }
        };
    }
    
    private void initializeLogic() {
        if ((FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null)) {
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        else {
            button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            _design(lin1, 40, 50, "#FFFFFF");
            _design(name, 70, 70, "#FFFFFF");
            _design(mob, 70, 70, "#FFFFFF");
            _design(email, 70, 70, "#FFFFFF");
            _design(pass, 70, 70, "#FFFFFF");
            sign_in.setPaintFlags(sign_in.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
            
            _LengthOfEditText(fillphone, 10);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int _requestCode, int _resultCode, Intent _data) {
        
        super.onActivityResult(_requestCode, _resultCode, _data);
        
        switch (_requestCode) {
            
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
    
    public void _design (final View _view, final double _radius, final double _shadow, final String _color) {
        //modified by ashishtechnozone
        android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable ab = new android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable();
        
        ab.setColor(Color.parseColor(_color));
        ab.setCornerRadius((float) _radius);
        _view.setElevation((float) _shadow);
        _view.setBackground(ab);
        
        
    }
    
    
    public void _private_design (final View _view, final double _radius) {
        //Gradient Code Starts Here
        int[] colors = {Color.rgb(138,41,81),Color.rgb(41,53,158)};
        android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable gd = new android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.Orientation.BR_TL, colors);
        gd.setCornerRadius((float) _radius); 
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {_view.setBackground(gd); } else {_view.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);}
        //End of Gradient Generator
    }
    
    
    public void _LengthOfEditText (final TextView _editText, final double _value_character) {
        InputFilter[] gb = _editText.getFilters(); InputFilter[] newFilters = new InputFilter[gb.length + 1]; System.arraycopy(gb, 0, newFilters, 0, gb.length); newFilters[gb.length] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter((int)_value_character); _editText.setFilters(newFilters);
    }
    
    
    @Deprecated
    public void showMessage(String _s) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), _s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    
    @Deprecated
    public int getLocationX(View _v) {
        int _location[] = new int[2];
        _v.getLocationInWindow(_location);
        return _location[0];
    }
    
    @Deprecated
    public int getLocationY(View _v) {
        int _location[] = new int[2];
        _v.getLocationInWindow(_location);
        return _location[1];
    }
    
    @Deprecated
    public int getRandom(int _min, int _max) {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt(_max - _min + 1) + _min;
    }
    
    @Deprecated
    public ArrayList<Double> getCheckedItemPositionsToArray(ListView _list) {
        ArrayList<Double> _result = new ArrayList<Double>();
        SparseBooleanArray _arr = _list.getCheckedItemPositions();
        for (int _iIdx = 0; _iIdx < _arr.size(); _iIdx++) {
            if (_arr.valueAt(_iIdx))
            _result.add((double)_arr.keyAt(_iIdx));
        }
        return _result;
    }
    
    @Deprecated
    public float getDip(int _input){
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, _input, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    
    @Deprecated
    public int getDisplayWidthPixels(){
        return getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    }
    
    @Deprecated
    public int getDisplayHeightPixels(){
        return getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    }}
```